# android launch another app resume screen in programmatically

Tags: android

Already use this code

```
Intent appIntent = getPackageManager().getLaunchIntentForPackage("your app package name ");
startActivity(appIntent );
```

Above code is always open main launcher not recent app open screen

Is there any way to load the current page/screen when it get loads from some other app?